# Arithmetic of Hamiltonian in canonical transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

I have the following Hamiltonian:

$$ \mathcal{H} = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(q-X(t)) + \dot{X}(t)p, $$

and I make the usual canonical transformation for the momentum:

$$ p \rightarrow p' = p + m\dot{X},$$

and complete the square, which **should** give the following:

$$ \mathcal{H}' = \frac{p'^2}{2m} + V(q - X(t)) - \color{red}{m\ddot{X}(t)q} - \frac{m\dot{X^2}}{2}.$$

I can get most of this expression apart from the one in $\color{red}{red}$.

This has to come from the cross term $(\frac{(\hat{p} \cdot m\dot{X}+m\dot{X}\cdot\hat{p})}{2m}),$ but I can't get the $q$ to come out.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you just substituting $p=p'-m\dot{X}$ into the Hamiltonian, assuming its value is unchanged, or did you check whether the new Hamiltonian's equations of motion are those of the old one?

Comment: Literally just substitution. Just arithmetic, tt has to be somthing with commutators that I can't see.

Comment: I thought so. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Generating_function_approach for $K=H+\text{other term}$ formulae, depending on which version of the transformation you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hamiltonian transforms according to the following rule:

$H^\prime = H - \partial_t f$, where $f=f(q,t)$ (1).

We can find this function by using that:

$p = p^\prime-\partial_qf=p^\prime-m \dot{X}$.

So we see that $f=m \dot{X}q +c , c \in \mathcal{R}.$   (2).

Plug equation (2) into equation (1) gives:

$H^\prime=H-\partial_t(m\dot{X}q+c)=H-m\partial_t(q\dot{X})$, now looking at the final form of the equation that you have to show I guess that $\dot{q}=0$ such that $H^\prime=H-mq\ddot{X}$. Where $H=(p^\prime)^2/2m+V(q-X(t))-m\dot{X}^2/2$ is the Hamiltonian you already derived.

*Warning*: I am not sure what exactly $q$ is in your case and whether $\dot{q}=0$ holds. This is something you should check yourself since I do not know the context and so on. But this works completely fine.

Comment: As a side note: The moral of the story is that you cannot always just plug in the transformed momentum into your Hamiltonian. In order to have this one must check whether $\partial_t f=0$ holds, i.e. whether $f=constant$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try a [type-2 generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) $$F_2(q,P,t)~=~\left(P-m\dot{X}(t)\right)q,$$
for a [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) $$(q,p,t)~\to~ (Q,P,t),$$ such that 
$$K-H ~=~\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial t}~=~\color{red}{-m\ddot{X}(t)q}, \qquad Q~=~\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial P}~=~q,  \qquad p~=~\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial q}~=~P-m\dot{X}(t). $$